# Custom Expression in Polars

Tags: python-polars, rust-polars

Is it possible to create custom expressions? I understand there is a path for custom functions using the `apply` or `map` methods, but would it be possible to create a custom expression in Rust that may then be available on the python side?

Comment: This may help you: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/tree/master/examples/python_rust_compiled_function